# Get the referral <script> object in JS in the source script

Tags: javascript, dom, widget

Assuming we have a script tag in html:

```
<script mycustom-attribute="sample-value" src="http://example.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

Now, is there anyway, where we can get the caller script object in "myscript.js" so that we can read `mycustom-attribute`. Of course we can use some id/class, but what if we want to refer it without its name/id/class. The idea is to use to embed widget without having a problem of conflicting id/name/class.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a custom attribute to work with, see [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859056/157247).

If there could be multiple scripts with the custom attribute, or for those who don't have a custom attribute to work with:

Assuming your `script` tag is as shown, without `async` or `defer`, then in top-level code in that script, you know reliably that it's the **last** `script` in the DOM, so:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var value = scripts[scripts.length - 1].getAttribute("mycustom-attribute");
```

If there may be an `async` or `defer`, you need to look by `src`, perhaps using the "[ends with](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors)" attribute selector (`$=`):

```
var script = document.querySelector("script[src$='myscript.js']");
var value = script.getAttribute("mycustom-attribute");
```

(There's also [`document.currentScript`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-currentscript), but it's *"...fallen out of favor in the implementer and standards community..."*.)

---

Side note: When using custom attributes, use the [`data-` prefix](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: So that means, there's  no direct method and we 'll have to explore DOM.

Comment: @Arfeen - Yes, since `document.currentScript` has fallen out of favor.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the script which has the custom attribute:

```
var script = document.querySelector('script[mycustom-attribute]');
if (script) {
    var value = script.getAttribute('mycustom-attribute');
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: **Doh!** Or that.